# React: How to conditionally style dropdown options?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Im trying to change the className of choosen objects in the mapped array with another array`(this.props.notPressAble)`. This is because i want some of the objects in the array to have another css style

```
handleOptions = () =>{
    let array = this.props.options.map((option, i) => 
    <a 
    key={i} 
    className={classes.dropdownoptions}>
    {option}</a>)

    for(let x = 0; x < this.props.options.length; x++)
    {
        if(this.props.notPressAble !== undefined)
        {
            for(let y = 0; y < this.props.notPressAble.length; y++)
            {
                if(x == this.props.notPressAble[y])
                {
                    array[x].props.className = classes.dropdownoptionsnotpressable
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return array
}
```

The code below is where i implement the class for readers too get a better understanding of my problem

```
 <SideBarContainers name="Planering" notPressAble={[0, 6, 11]}
 options={[
     "Aktiviteter:",
     "+ Ny Aktivitet",
     "Visa Alla Öppna",
     "Visa Försenat",
     "Visa Alla Stängda",
     "Visa Alla Kategoriserat",
     "Att göra:",
     "+ Ny Att göra",
     "Visa Alla Öppna",
     "Visa Alla Stängda",
     "Visa Alla Kategoriserat",
     "Personal planering:",
     "+ Ny post",
     "Visa Alla enkel"
```

]} />

The problem im having is that `array[x].props.className` is a readOnly value that cant be changed. Is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using for loops to loop over options and then notPressAble. You could just use includes function and decide which class to apply.

```
handleOptions = () => {
    let array = this.props.options.map((option, i) => {
      const cls = this.props.notPressAble.includes(i) ? classes.dropdownoptionsnotpressable : classes.dropdownoptions
      return (
        <a key={i} className={cls}>
          {option}
        </a>
      )
    });

    return array;
  };
```

If you still want to go with your current code then you need to clone the element you want to change and then make the changes like below.

```
//array[x].props.className = classes.dropdownoptionsnotpressable
array[x] = React.cloneElement(array[x], {className: classes.dropdownoptionsnotpressable});
```

Comment: i didnt know such a thing existed, thanks a lot man :)